# IP Address when Multiple NICs are Involved

Tags: tcp, winsock

I am writing a TCP server application using Winsock. The machine on which my server will run and the machine on which the client will run both have 2 NICs. The IP addresses involved are:

- Server NIC 1: 192.168.132.14 <-- This is the one I want to bind
- Server NIC 2: 192.168.132.15
- Client NIC 1: 192.168.132.16
- Client NIC 2: 192.168.132.17

QUESTION 1:
In my server application, if I use INADDR_ANY when binding my listening socket, which of my two IP addresses will be used? Would I be correct to assume that there's no telling and that I should just use inet_addr("192.168.132.14") in place of INADDR_ANY?

QUESTION 2:
How can the client control which IP address he uses when connecting to me? Would he simply call bind() before calling connect()? Am I liable to see him as connecting from either address (no telling which one) if he does not?

Comment: INADDR_ANY will bind to both NICs so as long as you don't have some other socket that is already listening (or will try to listen) to the same port on the other IP, you can use INADDR_ANY

source: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-441/F01.full/www/assignments/P2/htmlsim_split/node18.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When calling `listen()` on a server socket, binding to `INADDR_ANY` will bind the socket to all available local IPs on the machine.  That allows a client to connect to any of the server's IPs.  If the server uses `inet_addr()` instead, that will be the only IP that the server can accept client connections on.

When calling `connect()` on a client socket, it has to indicate a specific IP that the server is listening on.  If the client wants to pick which local IP it binds to for its endpoint of the connection, it can call `bind()` on itself before calling `connect()`.  If the client does not bind to a specific IP, or it binds to `INADDR_ANY`, the socket will use the first IP it finds that has an available route to the server IP being connected to.

Once the connection has been established, both parties can call `getsockname()` and `getpeername()` on their respective socket endpoints at any time to discover which IPs (and ports) are actually in use for that connection.